# Multiple form application saving color of second form to first form

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms-designer

So, I'm using:

```
            Me.ColorDialog2.ShowDialog()
    Me.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
    Dim bg2color As Color = ColorDialog2.Color
    My.Settings.MyBackgroundColor = bg2color
    My.Settings.Save()
    Me.BackColor = bg2color
```

For each for with different variables, I was using one colordialog, but tried two just to see if that was the issue. I can't figure out how to make each form save it's own individual color settings. I've even tried adding something like form2/form3.backgroundcolor = in the main form load events.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution is to use another application setting that you can use to store and retrieve with the type `System.Drawing.Color`. You have done this once, and so you can for the sake of persisting the background colors of another forms.

For example, you can create `myBackgroundColor2` in the settings for the second form. Then use `My.Settings.myBackgroundColor2` for the background color of the second form.

*Update:*

In form1:

```
Me.ColorDialog1.ShowDialog()
Me.BackColor = ColorDialog1.Color
Dim bg1color As Color = ColorDialog1.Color
My.Settings.MyBackgroundColor = bg1color
My.Settings.Save()
Me.BackColor = bg1color
```

In form2:

```
Me.ColorDialog2.ShowDialog()
Me.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
Dim bg2color As Color = ColorDialog2.Color
My.Settings.MyBackgroundColor2 = bg2color
My.Settings.Save()
Me.BackColor = bg2color
```

Now see the difference? On the second form, the setting variable that I have used is `My.Settings.MybackgroundColor2` instead of the one in form1. This means that each form stores their BGColor in each setting variable so it is impossible for them to share the same background color.

Comment: I think I may be missing something, can you elaborate? Even when removing this code from form1, and testing on form2, it still saves the color to form1, instead of form2.

Comment: Ok, I'll expand my answer for awhile.

Comment: @ShawnB Let me clarify, on what form is the ColorDialog located? Is it in the form1?

Comment: It is, yes. I even added a secondary colordialog to see if that was the issue, but it still does the same thing.

Comment: And you want to change the background color of form2 by configuring the ColorDialog located in form1?

Comment: I have a colordialog located on form2 as well, which I've been trying to manipulate. It seems to change the color just fine, but when it does, it reverts back to the loading color when I re-launch the application. But instead of the main form having it's color, it takes on the color you set on form 2. Same thing with form 3, the color goes to form1.

Comment: Now it seems that I understand you more. Updated my answer. Let me know if you have a problem.

Comment: It says mybackgroundcolor2 is not a member of Myapplication.My.MySettings?

Comment: So you don't added it yet. To add it, go to My Project -> Click Settings. In there you can see MyBackgroundColor but no MyBackgroundColor2. Add it manually there  by copying MyBackgroundColor Type and scope, just change the name into MyBackgroundColor2.

Comment: So, I added it, and it's not erroring, but it's not saving the color still. Unsure why. Though, it is now not saving the secondary form color to form1, so that's a plus.

Comment: What version of Visual studio are you using?

Comment: I don't usually do this, but take a look at my source code. Download it at http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=04949656355637984153.

Comment: Unfortunately, my work has most ext sites blocked, if you can post it in a code block here I can view it, it just won't allow downloads

Comment: Let us talk about it here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50570/color-dialog-fix

Comment: I only have a 6 reputation, so I cannot type, but I can read it.

Comment: No, but glad to help.

Comment: I was so focused on the settings function.. I forgot the load method for the saved setting. :|